Nginx Redirects All domains
proxy_cache_path /tmp/pleroma-media-cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=pleroma_media_cache:10m max_size=10g
                 inactive=720m use_temp_path=off;

upstream phoenix {
    server 127.0.0.1:4000 max_fails=5 fail_timeout=60s;
}

server {
    server_name    afardfediverse.ir;

    listen         80;
    listen         [::]:80;

    #location / {
    #  return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    #}
}

# Enable SSL session caching for improved performance
ssl_session_cache shared:ssl_session_cache:10m;

server {
    server_name afardfediverse.ir;

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;  # about 40000 sessions
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_trusted_certificate   /etc/letsencrypt/live/afardfediverse.ir/chain.pem;
    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/afardfediverse.ir/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/afardfediverse.ir/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    ssl_ecdh_curve X25519:prime256v1:secp384r1:secp521r1;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/activity+json application/atom+xml;

    client_max_body_size 16m;
    ignore_invalid_headers off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://phoenix;
    }

    location ~ ^/(media|proxy) {
        proxy_cache        pleroma_media_cache;
        slice              1m;
        proxy_cache_key    $host$uri$is_args$args$slice_range;
        proxy_set_header   Range $slice_range;
        proxy_cache_valid  200 206 301 304 1h;
        proxy_cache_lock   on;
        proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
        proxy_buffering    on;
        chunked_transfer_encoding on;
    proxy_pass         http://phoenix;
    }
}
server {
    listen      8080 ssl;
    server_name iamafard.ir;
    ssl_trusted_certificate   /etc/letsencrypt/live/iamafard.ir/chain.pem;
    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/iamafard.ir/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/iamafard.ir/privkey.pem;

    root /var/www/html/iamafard/wordpress;
}
root@srv6575115705:~# 

What's the issue?
All domains redirects to the first domain. I know that the problem is from nginx, and this is the config: where is the problem?
This problem happens when using this pleroma config (I added wordpress for the second domain)
What should I edit in this config to make it work? This is the only config, I don't have other ones.
All domains just redirects to first domain.
The operating system is debian 12
I have an pleroma on it but the problem is from nginx
Apache is not running , Only nginx
The WordPress document root is ok and tested
(Mods please approve this! , There is no refer to the domain)

Is afardfediverse.ir the first domain? Which domain is redirecting to it?

iamafard.ir is redirecting to afardfediverse.ir

Looking at your configuration, any request to port 80 will redirect to  afardfediverse.ir (as that is the value of $server_name in your first server block)

Commented that part and restarted nginx , No help!
